# How do you get the contextPath from JavaScript, the right way?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

Using a Java-based back-end (i.e., servlets and JSP), if I need the contextPath from JavaScript, what is the recommended pattern for doing that, any why?  I can think of a few possibilities.  Am I missing any?

**1. Burn a SCRIPT tag into the page that sets it in some JavaScript variable**

```
<script>var ctx = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>"</script>
```

This is accurate, but requires script execution when loading the page.

**2. Set the contextPath in some hidden DOM element**

```
<span id="ctx" style="display:none;"><%=request.getContextPath()%></span>
```

This is accurate, and doesn't require any script execution when loading the page.  But you do need a DOM query when need to access the contextPath.  The result of the DOM query can be cached if you care that much about performance.

**3. Try to figure it out within JavaScript by examining `document.URL` or the BASE tag**

```
function() {
    var base = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
    if (base && base.href && (base.href.length > 0)) {
        base = base.href;
    } else {
        base = document.URL;
    }
    return base.substr(0,
        base.indexOf("/", base.indexOf("/", base.indexOf("//") + 2) + 1));
};
```

This doesn't require any script execution when loading the page, and you can also cache the result if necessary.  But this only works if you know your context path is a single directory -- as opposed to the root directory (`/`) or the multiple directories down (`/mypath/iscomplicated/`).

**Which way I'm leaning**

I'm favoring the hidden DOM element, because it doesn't require JavaScript code execution at the load of the page.  Only when I need the contextPath, will I need to execute anything (in this case, run a DOM query).

Comment: I can for life not understand why *"but requires script execution when loading the page"* is such a big problem that you'd prefer to fallback to DOM fiddling/traversing. Can you please elaborate? Also, what exactly do you need to context path for? Perhaps there are other ways so that you don't need it at all.

Comment: JavaScript execution while loading the page blocks parallel downloads.  Maybe it doesn't matter with a one-liner.  DOM traversal might be more penalizing, but at least you have the option to delay the penalty till you absolutely need it (if you need it).  I'm not sure that a lookup by ID would be all that penalizing either.

Comment: I don't need the contextPath myself.  I was just bringing up a "what if".  Here's a possible example: I'm loading a JS file dynamically and need to know its path.  I can use an absolute path if I know the contextPath ahead of time, but if the contextPath changes, then my scripts break.  I can use a relative path, but that's dependent on the location of the parent HTML doc.  If I move the file, my page breaks.  Knowing the contextPath, I can protect myself from these types of breakages by having a dynamically-generated absolute path.

Comment: Assigning a global variable is basically a no-op in modern browsers. I would alone not use old fashioned *scriptlets* for this, but just EL. `var ctx = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}';`

Comment: @BalusC You are amazing. Thank you for always posting what you know about how to work with JSPs. Also, I can't get your suggestion to work. When I put it in a script tag, the EL is not recognized. And when I don't put it in a script tag, the error says that a variable is defined wrong. How do I do what you posted above?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments (particularly from BalusC), it's probably not worth doing anything more complicated than this:

```
<script>var ctx = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"</script>
```

Comment: Although tedious, I always preferred to have my JavaScript objects receive a property that defines the "baseUrl" or context. I would have a script tag in the jsp to "initialize" my JavaScript objects for the page, and pass the baseUrl into them there. This way I don't have to assume that some global variable is available.

Comment: @Mike M. Lin , Are there  any pitfalls if we use the option  fetching the path using document.url

Comment: can someone help me? I added the global variable in my javascript file but it is returning me the raw String "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" and not the contextPath of project..

Comment: @FelipeMosso It goes into your .jsp file, not your JavaScript file.

Comment: @MikeM.Lin thank you, I will try it later.. the <script></script> tags made me think I should add into the JavaScript file

Answer (score 46):

Got it :D

```
function getContextPath() {
   return window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
}
alert(getContextPath());
```

Important note: Does only work for the "root" context path. Does not work with "subfolders", or if context path has a slash ("/") in it.

Comment: This is the best answer! It doesn't mix jsp with javascript definitions

Comment: FWIW this fails if the context path has slash in it (e.g. `/foo/bar`).

Comment: I'm seeing window.location.pathname with a value like "/context/p1/p2/p3.html", so this suggestion returns "/context". But a Java web application may be deployed in the ROOT context, so the first component of the pathname is not a context string. I don't know a way to handle this using client-only script, which is a problem as I'm not using JSP or Servlets.

Comment: This does not return the context path. This returns the first path name of the URL which is not necessarily the context path.

Comment: I'm facing this problem for last two days.Finally I find the solution of that issue. Thanks a lot @Cedric

Comment: If you're going like this you might even consider hardcoding your context-path...

Answer (score 6):

I think you can achieve what you are looking for by combining number 1 with calling a function like in number 3.

You don't want to execute scripts on page load and prefer to call a function later on? Fine, just create a function that returns the value you would have set in a variable:

```
function getContextPath() {
   return "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
}
```

It's a function so it wont be executed until you actually call it, but it returns the value directly, without a need to do DOM traversals or tinkering with URLs.

At this point I agree with @BalusC to use EL:

```
function getContextPath() {
   return "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
}
```

or depending on the version of JSP fallback to JSTL:

```
function getContextPath() {
   return "<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />";
}
```

Comment: Cool idea, but this would actually be *more* overhead.  The because now I have a function declaration in addition to the variable assignment.  `function getContextPath() {..}` actually expands to `window.getContextPath = function() {..}`.  At this point I agree with BalusC that there's nothing wrong with something like `var ctx = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}';`.  It *is* about as close to a no-op as you can get.

Answer (score 5):

Reviewer the solution by this
Checking the solution of this page, make the following solution I hope it works:
Example:

Javascript:

```
var context = window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2)); 
var url =window.location.protocol+"//"+ window.location.host +context+"/bla/bla";
```

Answer (score 4):

I render context path to attribute of link tag with id="contextPahtHolder" and then obtain it in JS code. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link id="contextPathHolder" data-contextPath="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
    <body>
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var CONTEXT_PATH = $('#contextPathHolder').attr('data-contextPath');
$.get(CONTEXT_PATH + '/action_url', function() {});
```

If context path is empty (like in embedded servlet container istance), it will be empty string. Otherwise it contains contextPath string

Comment: Nice solution, works for me in my case of a Grails app and a gsp snippet like this: `${request.contextPath}`

Comment: This work for me using springboot with thymeleaf, made small modification.

In the HTML

       </html>
   

THEN IN JS
         var CONTEXT_PATH = $('#contextPathHolder').attr('data-contextPath');
         $.get(CONTEXT_PATH + 'action_url', function() {});

Answer (score 0):

A Spring Boot with Thymeleaf solution could look like:

Lets say my context-path is `/app/`

In Thymeleaf you can get it via:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        let contextPath    = /*[[@{/}]]*/
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```