# Ajax request is not calling Spring boot controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to call my Spring controller using Ajax and submitting a form.

Function always retrieves the error window. I tried changing the URL parameter to **"/profile"**, **"profile"** or **"PrivateAreaController/profile"**, but I keep getting the same error.

My `main.js` file and controller are placed in the following order:

```
-->Mainfolder
    -->src
       -->java
          -->controller
              -->PrivateAreaController.java
       -->resources
           -->static
              -->js
                 -->main.js
```

My controller is called `PrivateAreaController`

**Ajax Code**

```
$('#sampleForm').submit(
    function(event) {
        var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
        var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
        var data = 'firstname='
            + encodeURIComponent(firstname)
            + '&amp;lastname='
            + encodeURIComponent(lastname);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url : '@Url.Action("callingcontroller","PrivateAreaController")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : data,
            success : function(response) {
                alert( response );
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("not working");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**Spring code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody
        String processAJAXRequest(
                @RequestParam("firstname") String firstname,
                @RequestParam("lastname") String lastname   ) {
            String response = "";

            System.out.println("working");
            return response;
        }
```

**HTML form**

```
<form id="sampleForm" method="post" action="/profile">
         <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
         <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>
         <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

EDIT:

I found the answer.. i needed to add

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
```

before the `@RequesMapping` parameter and change the url parameter of the ajax call to url: 'http://localhost:8080/(your requestmapping parameter)

Comment: What's the error? The content of `data` doesn't look like valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.. i needed to add

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")

before the @RequesMapping parameter and change the url parameter of the ajax call to url: 'http://localhost:8080/(your requestmapping parameter)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using springboot with thymeleaf, made small modification to one of the answers on this post [How do you get the contextPath from JavaScript, the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615641/how-do-you-get-the-contextpath-from-javascript-the-right-way)

In the HTML

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <link id="contextPathHolder" th:data-contextPath="@{/}"/>
            <body>
                <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

THEN IN JS

```
  var CONTEXT_PATH = $('#contextPathHolder').attr('data-contextPath');
  $.get(CONTEXT_PATH + 'action_url', function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is error you are getting, Press F12 and go to Network tab and the press submit button now see the url, try adding url:"../your service URL..

Answer (score 0):

Well. I never seen this part before.

```
@Url.Action("callingcontroller","PrivateAreaController")
```

I normally do like as below:

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url : '/profile',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : data,
        success : function(response) {
            alert( response );
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("not working");
        }
 });
```

But it can have a problem with the contextPath.
So, What I do is adding 'request.getContextPath()/' as below:

```
     $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url : '${request.getContextPath()}/profile',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : data,
        success : function(response) {
            alert( response );
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("not working");
        }
    });
```

The contextPath has the URL of your start page.
For instance, 'www.google.com' or 'www.naver.com'

But in general, Since I personally use the contextPath a lot, I make a value and keep it.

```
var context = ${request.getContextPath()};
```

Then, your code will look neat and easy to reuse.

And also you can figure it out with the error attribute.

```
        error : function(err) {
            console.log("not working. ERROR: "+JSON.stringify(err));
        }
```

I hope this works out.